# Moving single-letter word to new line

Tags: javascript, jquery, typography

Is there any way to move a single-letter word to the next line by javascript? The code is from a database so I can't edit it manually. I've found a function which finds these words, but I have no idea how to put these to new line.

```
<div id="flop" class="foobar">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing 
    elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim 
    ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex a 
    commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in volue v 
    esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla p</div><br>
<button value="Go" onclick="foo();">Go</button>
```

```js
function foo(){
    var d = document.getElementById('flop');
    var t = d.innerHTML;
    var w = t.split(' ');       

    d.innerHTML = w[0];
    var height = d.clientHeight;
    for(var i = 1; i < w.length; i++){
        d.innerHTML = d.innerHTML + ' ' + w[i];

        if(d.clientHeight > height){
            height = d.clientHeight;
          if(w[i-1].length === 1){
              console.log(w[i-1]);
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: bring an example of what you want.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking

Answer (score 1):

May be you want to do something like this:

```js
function foo() {
  var d = document.getElementById('flop');
  var t = d.innerHTML;
  var w = t.split(/\s/);
  var s = ''; //  <---have a var to store the new html
  d.innerHTML = ''; // <--- empty the div
  for (var i = 0; i < w.length; i++) {
    if (w[i].length === 1 && i !== w.length-1) {
      s += '<br>' + w[i] + '<br>';
    } else {
      s += ' ' + w[i];
    }
    // here append the array value to the var s which holds the 
    // new html build. Idea here is to have a check for the length
    // of the current array value to 1 then add br tags after/before
  }
  d.innerHTML = s; // finally put the new html here.
}
```

```html
<div id="flop" class="foobar">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex a commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in volue v esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla p</div>
<br>
<button value="Go" onclick="foo();">Go</button>
```

Comment: It should only work if the letter is last one in the line, but thank you anyway.

Comment: What do you want then? Does this work the way you need it?

Comment: I want to move single-letter word to next line only if it's the last letter in the line, because in Polish it's incorrect to keep them at the end.

Comment: @P.Zietal It's almost impossible to 'detect' which letter is at the end of line in specific container, because browser renders site contents depending on website code.
You still can use following code. Just remove first <br> and change second one to &nbsp;

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, `\u000A` is the escaped Unicode character for newline.

If you can already identify the single-letter words, simply prepend `\u000A` to each word.

Comment: Probably need to prepend and append to get them on their own new line